# Using activity.finish in up button

Tags: android, up-button

I want to define an up button for my android application to go to parent activity. From some resources I found this code when up-button clicked:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
```

But I had a problem and it was that my activity needs some data for creation (Intent extras) and for this reason I replaced with this code:

```
getActivity().finish();
```

But some feeling tells me this is not a correct way for reaching to parent activity and maybe I will face to some runtime errors later. What do you think what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(sourceActivity.this,targetActivity.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("NameKey", yourValue); // for send a Value with a key name. yourValue can be every type value
  startActivity(myIntent);
  this.finish();
  // and for receive value from target activity
  Bundle extraGet = getIntent().getExtras();
  String receiveValue = extraGet.getString("NameKey");
```

also you can define `public static` your variable that can use it to every class and activities

i think you want this:

```
 Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this function can used for every key on Phone that pressed
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
                    // On Click KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP Commands
                    // here, every code want to execute
                    }
          return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
          }
```

**Update** (that you want ;-) )
in onCreate:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in main class :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Khosh begzare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is I want to have an up button on action bar of app. And I want to know how to implement its click event.

Comment: Thanks friend. But would you please to tell what should I put instead of Toast.make... to reach the parent activity? One solution is to use NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity()); but my activity needs some extras to start properly.